# Failing to init Hyperledger Fabric CA, "Failed to get user"

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I followed the below link to install the fabric:

https://www.mlgblockchain.com/setup-hyperledger-client.html

But getting an error

**server side**

```
root@amit-VirtualBox:/home/amit# fabric-ca-server init -b “admin:adminpw”
2017/09/15 10:40:20 [INFO] Home directory for default CA: /opt/Fabric-CA/server
2017/09/15 10:40:20 [INFO] Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054
2017/09/15 10:41:07 [INFO] 127.0.0.1:59210 POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: User not found
```

Both are running on the same server.

Comment: Can you run the server in debug mode:   fabric-ca-server start -d -b “admin:adminpw”  ?

Comment: /root/Documents/Blockchain/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverendpoint.go:44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2238
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP
 /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2568
net/http.(*conn).serve
 /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825
runtime.goexit
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197
2017/09/19 09:53:41 [INFO] 127.0.0.1:43548 POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: User not found"

Comment: Can you show us the contenct of the configuration file of the CA Server?

Answer (score 0):

**Try removing the invereted commas in the commands.**

Delete the server and client folder and follow the instructions from the blog avoiding the inverted commas.

**1.Initialize the server**

```
fabric-ca-server init -b admin:adminpw
```

**2.Start the server**

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw
```

**3.Enroll the Admin**

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

**4.Create new user and register it**

```
fabric-ca-client register -u http://localhost:7054 --id.name test --id.secret testpw --id.type client --id.affiliation org1.department1
```

Hopefully you wont face the error you received!

Assuming you have build fabric ca server and client successfully.